# AutoSizing Height TableViewCell - How to make UI elements have larger hitbox? [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I have a UITableViewCell that i created in storyboard using a prototype cell. I have everything properly set so that the height adjusts based on autolayout constraints. The 2 constraints that determine this are for a UITextField in the cell. The UItextField has a top and bottom constraint that go to the superview (which is the cell itself).

The problem is that if I adjust each constraint's constant to a higher value, it makes the cell larger as well as the UITextField. If I lower the constraints' constants to a lower value, it makes the UITextField smaller as well as the cell. What I want to have happen is make the UITextField take up more of the cell, but keep the cell at the current size. That way, the hit detection is alittle better so users don't tap the cell and miss the UITextField when doing so.

How can I do this? Is the only way possible using a fixed width/height of the UITextField? That would stink. Thanks.

Note: Not really looking for code. Moreso looking for an explanation (and/or images if it helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has to give your cell a size. You need to have height set for something in the cell that then can give the cell height.

You can set the margin on the uitextfield to 0,0,0,0 in relation to the uitableview cell which will mean its the same size as the cell. Then you can use heightforrowatindex to set the cell height.